# Expectation of Quadratic Product of Bernoulli Vector and Gaussian Matrix?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

I have a $K$-dimensional vector $z$ of Bernoulli random variables with success probabilities vector $p$ and a $K \times D$ dimensional matrix $A$ such that each row $A_k$ is a $D$-dimensional Gaussian random variable with mean vector $\mu_k$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma_k$. I would like to compute the following expected value:

$$ \mathbb{E}_{z, \{A_k\}}[\operatorname{diag}(z)\,  A A^T \, \operatorname{diag}(z)]$$

where $\operatorname{diag}(z)$ is a square $K \times K$ matrix with $z$ as its diagonal elements.

How can I do this?

Also, if anyone can suggest a better title, please let me know :)

Comment: If $z_i$ is independent from both $z_j $ and $A_j$, then the expected value is the matrix $\operatorname{diag}(p)\,  \bigl(\Sigma + \mu\mu^T\bigr)\, \operatorname{diag}(p)$.
Can we assume that these variables are independent?

Comment: Yes, they are independent!

Answer (score 1):

Define $B:=\mathrm{diag}(z)A = \pmatrix{&z_1 A_1& \\ &\vdots& \\ &z_K A_K}$.
Note that $M :=\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{diag}(z)\,  A A^T \, \mathrm{diag}(z)] = \mathbb{E}[BB^T]$.

Let's do some calculations:
$$M_{ij} = \mathbb{E}[(BB^T)_{ij}]=\mathbb{E}[z_i A_i (z_j A_j)^T]=\mathbb{E}[z_iz_jA_i{A_j}^T]=\mathbb{E}[z_iz_j]\,\mathbb{E}[A_i{A_j}^T]=\mathbb{E}[z_i]\,\mathbb{E}[z_j]\,\mathbb{E}[A_i{A_j}^T]=p_ip_j\bigl(\mathrm{Cov}(A_i, A_j) + \mathbb{E}[A_i]\mathbb{E}[{A_j}^T]\bigr) = p_i\bigl(\mathrm{Cov}(A_i, A_j)+\mu_i{\mu_j}^T\bigr)p_j$$

Hence the result is $$M = \mathrm{diag}(p)\bigr(\Sigma + \mu{\mu}^T\bigr)\mathrm{diag}(p)$$
where $\mu=\pmatrix{&\mu_1&\\&\vdots&\\&\mu_K&}$ and $\Sigma_{ij}=\mathrm{Cov}(A_i,A_j)$

Comment: I think this is almost correct. The one problem is that you can't just replace $z$ with $p$ in the expectation. To see why, suppose E[A A^T] = I and z is 1 dimensional. Then we have $E[z_1^2]= E[z_1] = p_1$. But your answer gives $p_1^2$.

Comment: You are right! The calculation of $M_{ii}$ must be treated separately